# github auhentication method to access only all my organization's repos

Tags: authentication, github

I've been reading the official documentation and various articles but it's unclear to me. My organization has multiple users and multiple repos. It would not be right to merely authenticate as a particular github user (Personal Access Tokens), because a colleague logging into the shared dev server could access another's private personal repos if they can authenticate as a particular github user. Having a single organization-level access key would not be right because we need to know which user pushed which commit to the repo. I need a method which says: "I am authenticating as user X for organization Y, I can do anything that user X can do for organization Y, without being able to do everything that a user X can do outside of organization Y". Which authentication method would be appropriate for this use case?

Comment: I would recommend looking at something like gogs or gitea - access is controlled using individual public SSH keys, and there's the benefit of self-hosting a github like environment if you're into that